# iOS 9 didRangeBeacons called more times. iOS-8 it was once every second

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager, ios9, ibeacon

`didRangeBeacons` method is almost getting called ***40 times every second in iOS 9***. However, in **iOS 8 and below it was getting called only once every second**. Because of this our code logic in `didRangeBeacons` is not working as expected.

Steps to Reproduce:

1. To any of your ViewController or AppDelegate, add the CLLocationManager delegates.
2. Initialise the location manager.
3. Start ranging -

   ```
   [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:savedRegion];
   ```
4. Just see how frequently didRangeBeacons is getting called.

> Expected Results:
>   Should get called once every second.
>
> Actual Results:
>   Is getting called more than 40 times every second

Version:
**iOS 9 and above**

Comment: How many `Region` objects do you have defined and enabled for ranging?  Are you sure you aren't getting 4 callbacks per second, one for each `Region`?

Comment: in iOS 8 - when ranging for one region its called once every second and twice every second if ranged for 2 regions. In iOS 9 - when ranging for one region its getting called once every second. However when ranged for 2 regions - its getting very unpredictable. Few times twice every second and some times 20-30 times every second. I'm not sure if its an iOS-9 bug or a deliberate change ?

Comment: What exact version of iOS do you see this on?  See my test results in an answer below that were unable to reproduce on 9.0.2

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't change any of the CLLocationManager properties in the didRangeBeacons method. This will cause the CLLocationManager calling the didRangeBeacons again and you will end up with lots of updates in a second.

I've experienced this with 'startUpdatingLocation' but should have the results.

Comment: Thanks. Helped me to debug. I was starting location update in didRangeBeacons and in didUpdateLocations I was restarting ranging for already ranging beacon region. Hence didRangeBeacons was called for every duplicate region(same UUID, identifier and major) added. 
Interestingly iOS8 seems to have considered duplicates and not restart if its already ranging for a region. iOS9 doesn't seem to do this.

Comment: Cool, glad it did help you :) It's indeed interesting why iOS8 differs from iOS9.

Comment: I missed this comment, @MadhuVSwamy.  Since you have solved this issue, please create a new answer your own question and accept it.  (You have to wait 24 hours before you can accept your own answer.)

Comment: @SjoerdPerfors To resolve delay of enter region and exit during suspended state, I'm restarting ranging in didUpdateLocation. In iOS-8 it works well, but in iOS 9 because of the above bug its not working. 
Is there are solution which you could help to avoid this repeated ranging in iOS 9 ? Or any workaround to get faster entry/exit in suspended without restarting ranging.

Comment: Sorry @MadhuVSwamy I dont know. Can't you just stop de locationmanager before starting ?

Answer (score 0):

Having heard multiple reports of this, I have tried to reproduce this without success.  For a test setup, I created one `CLBeaconRegion` object and registered it for ranging.  I then counted the number of callbacks to the `didRangeBeaconsInRegion` method, and divided it by the number of seconds since the test started to get a measurement of callbacks per second.

```
CLBeaconRegion *region = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:[[NSUUID alloc]initWithUUIDString:@"2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6"] identifier:@"test"];
[self.rangingLocationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion: region];

... 

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)iBeacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region {
  if (startTime == nil) {
    startTime = [[NSDate alloc] init];
  }
  long secsSinceStart = -[startTime timeIntervalSinceNow];
  callbacks++;
  NSLog(@"Ranging callbacks per second: %1.2f", 1.0*callbacks/secsSinceStart);
}
```

Here are my results from NSLog:

**iOS Version: 9.0.2 (13A452)
Phone Model: iPod Touch ME643LL/A**

2015-10-09 17:20:02.660 beaconTest[214:7044] Ranging callbacks per second: 1.03

**iOS Version: 8.3 (12F69)
Phone Model: iPod touch ME978LL/A**

2015-10-09 17:27:35.842 beaconTest[629:242941] Ranging callbacks per second: 1.02

The fact that I cannot reproduce doesn't mean this issue does not exist.  It is possible it was an issue with an earlier version of iOS 9 than is currently available.  It is possible that it only exists under certain conditions that I cannot test.

However, it is safe to conclude that not all iOS devices with 9.0.2 experience the symptoms described in this question.

Comment: You will be able to simulate this only if we restart ranging for an already ranging region. To handle suspended state, I had to do this. 
This was working fine in iOS 8. Somehow iOS9 treats it as a new region and restarts ranging, hence duplicate call backs.